# How to assign items to 2 sharepoint users

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

Through the ID column, I have 2 people I need to notify through email.

Example:

```
if id=1 notify x
if id=2 notify y
again if id=3 notify x
      if id=4 notify y
```

It will keep looping as the IDs increase.

Comment: ID will never change, why do you want to loop through this ?

Comment: Is it a list workflow or a site workflow ?

Answer (score -1):

These articles should help you 
[Link here](http://spcycle.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html) and
[Link here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/send-e-mail-in-a-workflow-11d5f9dd-955f-412c-b70f-cde4214204f4)

First, you need to use the "If current item fields equal value" (First Link) conditions then, send email (second link)